# GetSubwebsForCurrentUser throws 401

Tags: search, csom, site-collection

I am trying to get a list of subsites that are accessible to the user. I was initially using,

```
var query = context.Web.Webs.OrderBy(x => x.ServerRelativeUrl)
var sites = context.LoadQuery(query);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

But I was getting UnauthorizedException. So I tried using the GetSubwebsForCurrentUser,

```
WebCollection webs = clientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
clientContext.Load(webs);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However, here as well I am getting an Unauthorized Exception. Why am I getting an Unauthorized when GetSubwebsForCurrentUser should only return sites where current user has access?

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to achieve this?

Full Code:

```
    IEnumerable<Web> GetAllWebs(String username, String password, String url)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);

            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            clientContext.Load(web);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(web.Title);


            WebCollection webs = clientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
            clientContext.Load(webs);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            return webs;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you the admin ? If there is more code above, can you share that ?

Comment: @GautamSheth Updated original post with full code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your full code works as expected for Online or on-premise.
I think the issue come from:
1. The username, password or url used are incorrect
2. The account used doesn't have enough permissions to query SharePoint by CSOM, at least the account must have "ViewPages" permission.

Comment: Consider using CSOM search API, as it's faster abd probably you will not have described problems. You'll need full list of site urls to check them.

Answer (score 1):

Have modified/fixed your code and changed couple of things:

1) Added `passWord` inside foreach loop. Currently, its outside

2) Also added `AuthenticationMode` and set it to default.

3) Added method to check whether user is present in the site collection by using EnsureUser method.

Please try with the below code:

```
IEnumerable<Web> GetAllWebs(String username, String password, String url)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            passWord.AppendChar(c);
        }

        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, passWord);
        clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

        var rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
        var ensureUser = rootWeb.EnsureUser(userName);
        clientContext.Load(ensureUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Web web = clientContext.Web;

        clientContext.Load(web);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine(web.Title);

        WebCollection webs = clientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
        clientContext.Load(webs);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return webs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really comment (rep) and I don't have a real solution unfortunately, but I was recently having similar issues with my workflow.

[Unauthorised Error Creating Sub Site with Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234064/unauthorised-error-creating-sub-site-with-workflow/)

I really found that there was little value to be had from the error responses. I got bad request for the incorrect URL call, but I got a 401 response as soon as any parameter was out of place anywhere.

All I can say is that the 401 Unauthorized error is not necessarily related to permissions as much as the action of the code itself is not permitted, so I would read it more like a runtime error.

Comment: No this is certainly related to permissions because as soon as I make the user member of the site, I stop getting an exception.